# How to get the output dir of a file Logger?

Tags: java, logging

I have a logger configured with logging.properties file.
Specifically, it configures a filehandler with a pattern threw the property `java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern`

my property is defined as follow : `%t/MyDir/MyLog%u_%g.log`

How can I get the output directory of this file Handler in java code?

Comment: Assuming you can get the FileHandler instance, you could access [private File files](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/logging/FileHandler.java) attribute using reflection. A long shot though.

Answer (score -1):

You can read the log out directory by using LogManager & then reading the property "java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern" as:

```
import java.util.logging.LogManager;

LogManager.getLogManager().getProperty("java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern")
```

Comment: this return the property wich doesn't contain the output dir but a pattern with variable like %t

Comment: I tested it, my logging.properties has : java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=C:/D/logs/some.log and I get this value back. Please try.

Comment: I tried I have the key that i put in my question. according to the doc https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57471_01/bigData.100/data_processing_bdd/src/rdp_logging_config.html the default value is %t/edpLog%u%g.log
Definetely a wrong answer

Comment: I did not see any method that could reverse engineer the pattern. In case pattern is used, one way is to reuse/copy the java.util.logging.FileHandler.generate() method to get the log file name and pick the latest file being updated/locked by logger thread

Comment: This is why I ask if there is a clever way that i am not aware to do this ;)

Comment: @user43968 You can perform the `%t`, `%h`, and `%%` substitutions yourself easily enough (but not using String.replace methods).  It’s true there is no way to know the current values substituted for `%g` and `%u`, but those are normally used for the file name, not the directory, so you can probably ignore them and still be correct in nearly every case.